# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'COLOR_BGR2GREY'

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am getting the following error when running my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PyCharm/SDC_1/Lane_Finding.py", line 3, in <module>
grey = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GREY)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'COLOR_BGR2GREY'
```

The script:

```
1: import cv2 as cv 

2: image = cv.imread('solidWhiteRight.jpg')

3: grey = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GREY)
```

I only have the "opencv-contrib-python" package currently installed in my virtual environment as I saw this was an issue with similar problems. Do I need to install another package along with that? I am able to print the image variable and I get a matrix of values.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

When I write and save the image, the image comes back as a greyscale image. However when I display it using matplotlib.pylot, it converts the image to a multi colored image. Does anyone know why this would be?

Code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
path = 'solidWhiteRight.jpg'
image = cv.imread(path)
gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imwrite('grey_image.jpg', gray)
plt.imshow(gray)
plt.show()
```

[Result of plt.show:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Km1.png)

Comment: Try reading it in as a gray image by using image = cv.imread('solidWhiteRight.jpg',0)

Comment: It's an American spelling `BGR2GRAY` with an `A`.

Comment: Thanks Mark that fixed it

Comment: that "update" is an entirely new question. please review [ask].

Answer (score -1):

When displaying a grayscale image in pyplot, you need to supply a color map. In your case, try

```
plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
```

Comment: OP has "advanced to a new and different problem, which now requires a posting a new Question." I would not recommend _answering_ those amendments, if they're lumped into the original question.